# I am adding a new sheet using vba. I want to add the name of the added sheet on the first cell of the new sheet while it gets created. How to do that?

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of the below code, I am trying to add a new sheet in excel with the name as the name given by the user. I need the sheet to be created with the name also getting added on the cell (1,1) of the Added sheet?

```vb
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim shExists As Boolean
    
    Do
        sheetName = InputBox("Name of sheet", "Add sheet")
        If sheetName <> "" Then
            shExists = SheetExists(sheetName)
            If Not shExists Then
                Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
                MsgBox "The sheet " & (sheetName) & " is successfuly made", , "Result"
            Else
                MsgBox "The name is already present, please enter a new name", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Name"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Please enter the OSAT", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Warning"
            'Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop Until Not shExists Or sheetName = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the new sheet to a variable to get access to it:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
End With

With ws
    .Name = sheetname
    .Cells(1, 1) = sheetname
End With
```

Furthermore I am referencing the workbook where the sheet should be created, explicitly by `ThisWorkbook` (=workbook containing the code). This makes the code more reliable.